# How to set Build Action on a file - Advanced Properties Not Displayed in properties window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

There is no advanced properties settings available for the files in my ASP NET 4.0 project in VS2010. I have looked through the options settings and I dont see how to turn them on.

I am looking for the Build Action setting so I can set to Embedded Resource.

Is this only available if the project is compiled to an assembly DLL?

[image]

Here's a screen shot from 4guysfromrolla sample. Note that their sample is a user control.

Comment: It is not an advanced property and not an option setting.  Post a screen shot of the Properties window with the selection in the Solution Explorer window visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research I found that a file's Build Action is in fact only available on a project that compiles to an EXE or DLL such as a web control. It is not available for files within an ASP NET application.

Answer (score 8):

The response marked as the answer is not correct. These properties are available for ASP.NET applications, but only if the project type is a web *application*.

Files on *websites*, in contrast, do not have these properties. The reason is that the Build Action, for example, is stored in the project file. Since websites lack project files, the Build Action cannot be set.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot is of the Properties Window.  The selected item is in the Solution Explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to properties, select a property from properties you want to build, click on that, a window will open. Choose the desire file from your PC and Add there. Now you can use the file in your project.