# Visual Studio 2010 - Where to find or activate 'Build Action' properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, publishing

I'm trying to include `.rdlc` file on my project when publishing. I found that I have to change the `Build Action` properties. Where can I find that or how can I view and edit that? As you can see, the property window displays only the `File Name` and the `Full Path`

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: check this post. It might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498245/how-to-set-build-action-on-a-file-advanced-properties-not-displayed-in-propert

Comment: So that's not possible?