# Set Build action on file in Visual STudio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have an error with Unsupported Operation which is caused from what it sounds like is the Build Content of my crystal report file not being set to Content.  I've see several people comment on that but I can't seem to find how to set that in VS 2017.  Any clues?

Here is an article in 2010 that shows just right clicking on the file:
[How to set Build Action on a file - Advanced Properties Not Displayed in properties window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498245/how-to-set-build-action-on-a-file-advanced-properties-not-displayed-in-propert/17354946)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had built a "website" and to change that you have to have a "web application" so looks like I'll be rebuilding the entire program.